# Remover e adicionar elementos dependendo da resolução

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia remover uma *navbar* de uma determinada resolução? Exemplo: em resolução menor que 1024x768 uma das *navbars* desaparece e uma outra *navbar* vira o botão de *toogle*? Isso é feito pelo less ou media-queries. Lembrando que estou utilizando Bootstrap.

O site em questão é esse: http://goo.gl/aZOjTS

Então eu gostaria que a *navbar* azul sumisse a partir de uma certa resolução, e a *navbar* branca virasse o *toogle*.

Comment: Você tem acesso ao CSS?

Comment: Sim, eu tenho, mas não tenho acesso ao Sass

Answer (score 7):

Use [Media Queries](http://www.devmedia.com.br/utilizando-css-media-queries/27085)

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  #navbar{display: none;}
  .btn-toggle{display: block;}
}
```

Por padrão deixe o botão toggle com "display: none", quando chegar nesse tamanho de 1024 ele vai esconder a #navbar e mostrar o botão.

Não esqueça de adicionar o "meta viewport" no `<head> </head>` do HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[**Exemplo JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ncvrd92u/)

Comment: Então, fazer sumir beleza mas e para fazer aparecer o botão de toogle?

Comment: Editei a resposta para entender melhor.

Comment: Então, eu ainda não entendi como esconder a navbar, o toggle aparece mas a navbar n some

Comment: Olha na resposta um exemplo no JSFiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Para você alterar o layout de acordo com uma resolução use no CSS o Media Screen:

Esse exemplo abaixo demonstra que se o navegador possuir uma largura máxima de 767px ele vai fazer as alterações justificadas.

```
header .contato .mailtopo, header .contato .dados .campo .siga{display:block;}
header .dados-menu ul{display:block;}
header a.menu-mobile {display:none;}

@media screen and (max-width:767px){
    header .contato .mailtopo, header .contato .dados .campo .siga{display:none;}
    header .dados-menu ul{display:none;}
    header a.menu-mobile {display:block;}
}
```

Ou seja, basta criar o layout que você quer para a resolução menor e um para a resolução maior e dizer ao CSS qual exibir de acordo com o tamanho da tela.
Se der para ajustar uma classe é melhor, caso não dê, crie outra TAG e deixe ela oculta até que a resolução mude e você exiba ou oculte.

Para forçar a resolução em mobile (tirar a função zoom), use a meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
```

Espero ter ajudado.